# How to fix this error "GC overhead limit exceeded in Eclipse"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, performance

How to fix this error "GC overhead limit exceeded in Eclipse". This problem was occurred when I used graphical layout from ADT android.

Comment: filter by message: ^(?!.*(GC)|(Cache)).*$. :P when using Google Maps API it generates a lot of GC messages in LogCat, which is removed by doing this. Not a solution though. But in case or app works fine despite the warning, this is a neat way to remove unwanted logs.

Answer (score 20):

eclipse.ini file can be edited.
Increase the values for memory usage.
Please see the sample eclipse.ini file below.

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M

-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

--launcher.appendVmargs

-showsplash

org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

512m

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

--launcher.appendVmargs

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-Xms512m

-Xmx1024m
```

[image: The changed area in Eclipse.ini file]

Comment: Where to find my eclipse.ini ?

Comment: @DhirenParmar, you will find it inside the eclipse folder that you would have got after unzipping the .zip or .tar file.

Comment: Any idea why there are two entries for `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize`? (Interestingly my eclipse.ini had the same).

Answer (score 0):

MAC / IOS Users

> RightClick on Eclipse.app and then click on Show Package Content
>   Now Open Content folder to find the eclipse.ini file and edit

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -Xmx:G1GC:1024 algorithm to fix it in config file which loads when app start